# How to send payload data using sitebricks web client using http delete method

Tags: java, http, sitebricks

I am using sitebricks http client to send http requests to a rest service. My question is how to send a payload data with delete ? post method accepts data as a parameter

```
WebClient<SubnetId> client = web().clientOf(deleteUser()).transports(User.class).over(Json.class);

//client.post(user) <-- this is OK ! 

client.delete(); // <-- delete does not accepts user !!!
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, a good discussion raised in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-sitebricks/A2OTLFKOICI) which is somewhat the answer.